# Square Connect Validate Fields

Tags: square-connect

I set up square connect api and my form submits just fine. My problem is I am trying to submit the payment and also email additional information to myself. If everything gets filled out then the code works perfectly but When I call requestCardNonce(event); [it only requires the fields to generate the Nonce to be filled in and not the rest of the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xTbc.jpg) even tho I have them as required. [If i remove requestCardNonce(event); all fields are required like they should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G1os.jpg) Is there a way i can get validation on all of my fields to work with square connect api?

```
<form id="nonce-form" action="include/process-card.php" method="post">


                <div class="sec1crt-frmlft">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-toplft">
                                <center><img src="images/hdng-icon1.png" class="hdng-icon"></center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-toprgt">
                                <p class="txt2-chk">Billing Information</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-content1">
                            <div class="frmelements">
                                <label for="FirstName">First Name<span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon1.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="ft-input" autocomplete="off" id="FirstName" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="frmelements">
                                <label for="LastName">Last Name<span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon1.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="ft-input" autocomplete="off" id="LastName" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="frmelements">
                                <label for="Email">Email <span>*</span> </label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon3.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" class="ft-input" autocomplete="off" id="Email" 
                                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="frmelements">
                                <label for="Address">Address<span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon5.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="Address" class="ft-input" autocomplete="off" id="Address" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="frmelements short1">
                                <label for="State">State<span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon7.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <select name="State" class="ft-input" id="State" class="required" required>
                                        <option value="" onclick="" selected="">Select State</option>
                                        <option value="AL" onclick="">REMOVED TO SHOR</option>

                                 </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="frmelements short2">
                                <label for="City">City<span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon6.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="City" class="ft-input"  autocomplete="off" id="City" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="frmelements short1">
                                <label for="sq-postal-code">Zip Code <span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon8.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="sq-postal-code" class="ft-input"  autocomplete="off" id="sq-postal-code" 
                                    pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="frmelements short2">
                                <label for="Phone">Phone Number <span>*</span></label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon4.png"></center>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="Phone" class="ft-input"  autocomplete="off" id="Phone" 
                                    pattern="^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sec1crt-frmrgt">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-toplft">
                                <center><img src="images/hdng-icon2.png" class="hdng-icon"></center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-toprgt">
                                <p class="txt2-chk">Payment Information</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-content2">        

                            <div class="lwrform">                          
                                <div style="display:block;" id="cardDiv">

                                    <div class="clearall"></div>
                                    <img src="images/cards.png" class="cards">
                                    <div class="clearall"></div>

                                    <div class="frmelements short1">
                                        <label for="sq-amount">Payment Amount<span>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="field">  
                                        <div class="icon-box">
                                        <center><img src="images/frmicon9.png"></center>
                                    </div>                                              
                                            <input data-threeds="pan" type="text" maxlength="16" id="sq-amount" name="sq-amount" class="ft-input" 
                                            pattern="^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="frmelements">
                                        <label for="sq-card-number">Card Number<span>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="field">  
                                        <input data-threeds="pan" type="text" maxlength="16" id="sq-card-number" name="sq-card-number" class="ft-input noicon" 
                                        pattern="^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="frmelements short1">
                                        <label for="sq-expiration-date">Expiration Date<span>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="field"> 
                                        <input data-threeds="pan" type="text" id="sq-expiration-date" name="sq-expiration-date" class="ft-input noicon" required>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 

                                    <div class="frmelements short2">
                                        <label for="sq-cvv">CVV<span>*</span></label>
                                        <div class="field">
                                        <input type="text" class="ft-input noicon" name="sq-cvv" id="sq-cvv"  maxlength="4" 
                                        pattern="^[0-9]{3,4}$" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="frmelements short2">
                                        <a href="cvv.php" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><p class="txt4-chk">What is this?</p></a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                    <!--
                    After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden input field.
                  -->
                  <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearall"></div>
                            <div class="frmelements btn-element">
                           <input type="submit" value="" id="sq-creditcard" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)"
                               class="button-credit-card">

                            </div>

                            <center><img src="images/postal-crt.png" class="postal-crt"></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: you definitely can. could you be more specific with which validation you want? Also it looks like you have some unnecessary code, you don't need to supply `inputs` in the payment form.

Comment: I just want to make sure all of the fields are filled in before the form submits

Comment: Before you generate the nonce you could iterate through the non square fields to see if they are filled in. That might be the easiest way.

Comment: alright, i was hoping i could iterate through all fields at the same time but i guess to the average user they wont be able to tell the difference. Thank you for the help!